# How to Reproduce Multiple Product Setting Changes

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, product-attribute

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a process that I've manually written out for "Discontinuing" a product on our site. E.g. Remove from all categories, change "Brand" to "Discontinued," set stock to "Discontinued," etc.

This can be done with some efficiency/consistency via CSV, but that's a hassle, especially when you only need to discontinue 1 product.

Is there an extension/some solution that would let me create something like a macro that would change/modify all of these settings with a click from WITHIN Magento admin?

I would hoping attribute sets would do this, but this just controls which attributes show, now what they are set to.

I'm fairly certain many companies have needed solutions like this for efficiency/consistency. It would really suck to have to build it from scratch.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Part of what you need is already by default in Magento.
Just use the products grid, check the checkboxes for the products you want to modify then select from the top right selector `Update attributes`. Then you will will see a screen with all the common attributes for all the products you selected and the stock attributes. Change what needs to be changed and click on 'Save'.

The only think that is missing is bulk remove from all categories.
But if you have a product in 1 or 2 categories, you can just edit the category/categories and from the tab `Ascociated products` remove the products that are discontinued.

In case that does not fit your needs here is the code that removes a product from all the associated categories. You can put that in a controller and make a button that calls the action.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$product->setCategoryIds(array())->save();
```

Comment: Nice. Will check this out.

Comment: There's no way to save a set up attribute updates though, right?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "here's no way to save a set up attribute updates though"

Comment: Let's say I want have 10 attribute changes. Is there a way to save them like "Discontinuation Changes" so that, in the future, I can apply them again, without having to enter them all over again?

Comment: By default you can not do that. But again, you can create your own action that does this.